# Table row exceeded the column count

Tags: html, w3c-validation

This error message from W3C Validator. Is this a major problem?

> Line 342, Column 15: A table row was 12 columns wide and exceeded the column count established by the first row (1).

Comment: Depends on the HTML in question, which you haven't shown us.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It does suggest that it may not render uniformly in all browsers. You should probably use `colspan` as required to ensure that all rows have the same number of columns.